# nrows function in xlrd not returning the recent row values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

I am a beginner in python learning. For one of my validations I need to return the no of rows written each time. So, I have written the code below but the nrows function is not returning the recent row's values.

```
  import xlwt
  import xlrd
  Task1= xlwt.Workbook()
  sheet1 = Task1.add_sheet("Task_details1")
  Task1.save('C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Task1.xls')
  book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Task1.xls')
  sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Task_details1")

  def return_rows():
      return book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows

  class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
      for i in range(20):
          sheet1.write(i,0,i)
          Task1.save('C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Task1.xls')
          print return_rows()

  test1=test()
```

Function definition version 1:

```
       def return_rows():
         book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Task1.xls')
         sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Task_details1")
         return book.sheet_by_index(0).nrows
```

Comment: This is a bit messy. What is it really that you are trying to do? Are you trying to create a `class` which creates a worksheet and reads the number of rows in the first sheet?

Comment: I want to get the nunber of rows each time when it's updated with value

Comment: What's the `class` for? If you're after the number of rows in a sheet, you don't need the `class`. Just a function alone could get the job done.

Comment: Thanks. i have found the solution for my problem

Comment: Mind sharing your solution with the community?

Comment: The actual problem is i am opening the excel before entering the value in it. Please refer my Function definition version 1

Comment: I wrote [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0fxpc5snuo0syy5/MakeExcel.py?dl=0) as an answer since you were working with `classes`. It should help with the structure of your program.